# Ionic scroll to item with Virtual Scroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a list with big data.
In order to make the scrolling not lag, I am using Virtual Scroll, like this:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="sections">
    <div  *virtualItem="let section" class="section" [attr.id]="section.chapterNum">
      <h4 *ngIf="section.Chapter !=''">{{section.Chapter}}</h4>
      <h5 [ngClass]="section.Section_Title">{{section.Section_Title}}</h5>
      <div [innerHTML]="section.Section_Body | sanitizeHtml"></div>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

I also have a need for jumping to specific parts of the list, which I did like this (before applying the Virtual Scroll):

```
GoToSection(chapter: number, section: string) {
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(section);
    let yOffset;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if (+el[i].parentElement.id == chapter) {
        yOffset = (el[i] as HTMLElement).offsetTop;
      }
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 0)
    }, 300);
}
```

However, when I try to use this method, it shows a blank screen, since it didn't render the scrolled element yet and couldn't find it.
Is there a different way to scroll to an element with Virtual Scroll?

If not, is there an alternative option to Virtual Scroll? (Infinite Scroll isn't an option)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the [angular2-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll) package myself (which is the one I assume you are referencing), but I know that the Angular Material2 team is working on adding virtual scrolling to their library and they have an [open PR for adding "scrollTo" functionality for virtual scroll lists of fixed size](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11498).

By examining their implementation, you should be able to build a virtual "scrollTo" function for your use case (assuming you're dealing with a "Fixed Size" list). Here is some of the relevant code from that PR, but [you'll really want head over and examine their full implementation](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11498):

```
  /**  Scrolls to the offset on the viewport. */
  scrollToOffset(offset: number, options = { smooth: false, lazy: false }) {
    const viewportElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const top = this.orientation === 'vertical' ? offset : 0;
    const left = this.orientation === 'horizontal' ? offset : 0;

    let shouldScroll = true;
    if (options.lazy) {
      const currentOffset = this.measureScrollOffset();
      const currentOffsetEnd = currentOffset + this.getViewportSize();
      shouldScroll = offset < currentOffset || offset > currentOffsetEnd;
    }

    if (shouldScroll) {
      if (options.smooth && supportsSmoothScroll()) {
        viewportElement.scrollTo({ left, top, behavior: 'smooth' });
      } else {
        if (this.orientation === 'vertical') {
          viewportElement.scrollTop = top;
        } else {
          viewportElement.scrollLeft = left;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /** Scroll the viewport to the specified index. */
  scrollToIndex(index: number,  options = { smooth: false, lazy: false }) {
    const contentSize = this.measureRenderedContentSize();
    const offset = this._scrollStrategy.getScrollOffsetForIndex(index);
    this.scrollToOffset(offset, options);
  }
```

And in a file associated with the `this._scrollStrategy` object:

```
  /** Get the offset for the given index. */
  getScrollOffsetForIndex(index: number) {
    return index * this._itemSize;
  }
```

Also, if you do build something, I imagine the angular2-virtual-scroll project would welcome a PR from you.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks too complicated for me :)

Comment: Also, I'm not using the package you mentioned, but rather Ionic's built in Virtual Scroll

Comment: @amitairos gotcha :). I think the answer to your question then (_"Is there a different way to scroll to an element with Virtual Scroll"_) is "not at the moment, no". [Looking at the ionic virtual scroll source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/v3/src/components/virtual-scroll/virtual-scroll.ts), they don't implement a "scrollTo" method. Also, I'm not sure *any* angular virtual scroll libraries currently implement one. So you'd have to implement the function yourself or wait for it.

Comment: In general, implementation shouldn't be too bad. Assuming you are dealing with fixed height items, you can easily calculate the virtual height of the viewcontainer (number of items x item height). If given the index of a particular item, some simple math should be able to calculate where in the container it is. I imagine things get *way* more complicated for non-fixed height items though.